# Problemas en al configuracion de laravel spatie backup (POSTGRESQL)

Tags: laravel-5, postgresql

Estoy tratando de crear un respaldo de BD para un sistema que estoy desarrollando, no logro que funcione me marca demasiado errores he se en que estoy mal.

Error: php artisan backup:run

Backup failed because The dump process failed with exitcode 1 : General error : C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/pg_dump: illegal option -- optionname=optionvalue
Prueba pg_dump

les añadiré mi código para que se visualice mejor el problema, dentro del:

**database.php**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],


        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'almacen'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'postgresql'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'Mangasama1'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
            'dump' => [
           'dump_binary_path' => 'C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin', // only the path, so without `mysqldump` or `pg_dump`
           'use_single_transaction',
           'timeout' => 60 * 5, // 5 minute timeout
           'exclude_tables' => ['table1', 'table2'],
           'add_extra_option' => '--optionname=optionvalue',
        ] ,
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer body of commands than a typical key-value system
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'predis'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
        ],

    ],

];
```

**backup.php**

```
<?php

return [

    'backup' => [


        'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'laravel-backup'),

        'source' => [

            'files' => [

                'include' => [
                    base_path(),
                ],

                'exclude' => [
                    base_path('vendor'),
                    base_path('node_modules'),
                ],


                'follow_links' => false,
            ],


            'databases' => [
                'pgsql',
            ],
        ],


        'database_dump_compressor' => null,

        'destination' => [

            /*
             * The filename prefix used for the backup zip file.
             */
            'filename_prefix' => '',

            /*
             * The disk names on which the backups will be stored.
             */
            'disks' => [
                'local',
            ],
        ],

        /*
         * The directory where the temporary files will be stored.
         */
        'temporary_directory' => storage_path('app/backup-temp'),
    ],


    'notifications' => [

        'notifications' => [
            \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifications\BackupHasFailed::class => ['mail'],
            \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifications\UnhealthyBackupWasFound::class => ['mail'],
            \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifications\CleanupHasFailed::class => ['mail'],
            \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifications\BackupWasSuccessful::class => ['mail'],
            \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifications\HealthyBackupWasFound::class => ['mail'],
            \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifications\CleanupWasSuccessful::class => ['mail'],
        ],

        /*
         * Here you can specify the notifiable to which the notifications should be sent. The default
         * notifiable will use the variables specified in this config file.
         */
        'notifiable' => \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifiable::class,

        'mail' => [
            'to' => 'davesconcha@hotmail.com',
        ],

        'slack' => [
            'webhook_url' => '',

            /*
             * If this is set to null the default channel of the webhook will be used.
             */
            'channel' => null,

            'username' => null,

            'icon' => null,

        ],
    ],


    'monitor_backups' => [
        [
            'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'laravel-backup'),
            'disks' => ['local'],
            'health_checks' => [
                \Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Monitor\HealthChecks\MaximumAgeInDays::class => 1,
                \Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Monitor\HealthChecks\MaximumStorageInMegabytes::class => 5000,
            ],
        ],

        /*
        [
            'name' => 'name of the second app',
            'disks' => ['local', 's3'],
            'health_checks' => [
                \Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Monitor\HealthChecks\MaximumAgeInDays::class => 1,
                \Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Monitor\HealthChecks\MaximumStorageInMegabytes::class => 5000,
            ],
        ],
        */
    ],

    'cleanup' => [

        'strategy' => \Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Cleanup\Strategies\DefaultStrategy::class,

        'default_strategy' => [


            'keep_all_backups_for_days' => 7,

            'keep_daily_backups_for_days' => 16,


            'keep_weekly_backups_for_weeks' => 8,

            'keep_monthly_backups_for_months' => 4,


            'keep_yearly_backups_for_years' => 2,


            'delete_oldest_backups_when_using_more_megabytes_than' => 5000,
        ],
    ],
];
```

dondtro del archivo env tengo esto:

```
DB_CONNECTION= pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=almacen
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=Mangasama1
```

espero que me puedan ayudar a entender que es lo que esta fallando

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás indicando los valores de ejemplo en el atributo "add_extra_option" del fichero database.php

```
'pgsql' => [
            [...]
           'add_extra_option' => '--optionname=optionvalue',
        ]
```

Por eso te da el error: Backup failed because The dump process failed with exitcode 1 : General error : C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/pg_dump: **illegal option -- optionname=optionvalue** Prueba pg_dump

En ese atributo deberías indicar las opciones que necesites de la herramienta pg_dump qué es la que por debajo está haciendo el backup.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/app-pgdump.html

Por ejemplo, si quieres indicar que el backup se realice utilizando 2 jobs paralelos puedes indicar:

```
'pgsql' => [
            [...]
           'add_extra_option' => '--jobs=2',
        ]
```

O si no necesitas indicar opciones adicionales, puedes quitar ese atributo.